# How can I know that my weight is enough according to my height and age?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, weight-gain

How can I know that my weight is enough according to height and age . I think my weight is less according to height and age.                                           I am 22 years old , my height is 5.3 and weight is only 47kg . How can I gain weight through healthy food . Food that don't damage my stomach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I know that my weight is enough according to height and age?

There is a [standardized chart (and calculator)](https://www.rush.edu/health-wellness/quick-guides/what-is-a-healthy-weight) which you may find helpful.  However, this is the sort of thing that relies on statistical averages, and there's lots of people that this chart would lead to an inaccurate conclusion, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your nutrition will determine your size while your activities will determine your shape.

The quality of food consumed is irrelevant with regard to gaining or losing weight, only the caloric quantity will make a difference in how much you weigh. You also cannot merely eat healthy to gain healthy weight, inactivity will ensure that you are only gaining fat. There is only one way to gain healthy weight, and that is to be in a slight caloric surplus while being reasonably active for that surplus.

How do you know if your weight is enough? Look in the mirror. There is nothing wrong with being thin, but you can certainly be too thin. As long as you don’t look like an actual skeleton you’re probably fine. There are several problems with weight charts, and one of them is a lack of consideration for different body types. Some people have very petite skeletons and are naturally small, some people have bigger skeletons and are naturally large. The mirror is a good judge, and if you cannot trust yourself, find a trustworthy doctor.